# Accessing EOS from the front-end Javascript without NodeJs backend or cleos

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am looking for a library, like the Ethereum's web3js, for accessing EOS via the web using Javascript. Ideally, I want users to enter their EOS account name and let me query the main net (via node producer API endpoints) for various public account matters.

Anything available yet?

Comment: any updates or new library being developed?

Answer (score 3):

Basically nodeos is providing a [REST interface](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference) which you can query and use for blockchain communication. You just need an address for your local or a public nodeos endpoint.

However this is getting even easier with eosjs. This can be found [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs). You can install it via npm and import/require the library in your code. Then you can access the blockchain data.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about nodejs based eosjs but wanted to see if there is a JS library (soft of like jQuery for EOS) that web developers can include from a CDN and access blockchain public data.  Do you think a wrapper like this is needed to widen the reach of EOS blockchain? I really don't see typical web devs running NodeJS backend and then accessing eosjs that connects to their node server.  Thoughts?

Comment: In my opinion the possibility to fetch an arbitrary node via the REST interface is what you need for plain HTML/JS coding (like you compared it to jquery). To code a library around that would be quite easy to implement. But most of modern WebDevs already run NodeJS backends to host their single page applications like React or Angular Apps. So for most of the web devs eosjs is the right choice and the reach is very wide. NPM and its ecosystem is perfectly addressed by that.